# How To Get Some Data From WordPress Database Using WordPress $wpdb Query?

Tags: wp-query, database, query, wpdb, sql

I am trying to get some data from WordPress database tables in a plugin. For that, I am using the below code...

```
global $wpdb;
$findID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'hello-world'");
echo $findID;
```

But it not giving me the post ID in `echo`? Is there anything wrong...???

Comment: I checked again and found that it was my coding problem and after fixing that, the upper one is also working. You can also use the below answer one too...

Comment: @ialocin Ok. Done...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to clarify the [`get_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable) method of [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) does work just fine in this context:

```
global $wpdb;
$helloworld_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'hello-world'");
echo $helloworld_id;
```

Actually it is more practical in this context, because a single variable is returned, which is what is actually wanted.

Comment: Thanks for confirming me that I shared the right code but the problem was in my other codes so its ok now...

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution and the correct query to fetch one data from WordPress database is below one.

```
global $wpdb;
$findID = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'hello-world'");
echo $findID[0]->ID;
```

Comment: Don't know what the problem in your setup was/is but using `get_var` should work just fine. There shouldn't be the need to use `get_results`, which in this scenario is additionally a bit impractical.

Comment: I checked again and found that it was my coding problem and after fixing that, the question one is also working fine.

Comment: the correct syntax is

`global $wpdb;
$tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'leaguemanager_person_status';
$findID = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $tableName WHERE post_name = 'hello-world'");
echo $findID[0]->ID;`